# What does [no-] mean in git manual?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

My assumption now is that it means the opposite of what the command will do without adding the `no-` prefix, but I have trouble getting confirmation on this.

So, let's say in `git update-index` manual. I can find the flag `--[no-]assume-unchanged` specified as one of the possible flags to the command. What does `[no-]` mean here?

Comment: The manual page for `git update-index` has an example (below a dedicated section) explaining what `--no-assume-unchanged` implies. If it does not cover your question, please be more specific.

Comment: It means that you can optionally include the text within the square brackets. Then, of course, if you do, it inverts the meaning of the option. I don't know if this is standardised anywhere, but it's pretty standard stuff for command-line programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prefix `--no` on an option has only rough meaning, and even that only by convention.  There is no general documentation for it because it has no general meaning.  You can't just pick any random option and stick a `--no` on it; this works only if a separate `--no-xyzzy` option is defined (which, in principle, *could* do anything; but which, for usability, always follows the loose, conventional definition).

And that definition is: `--no-xyzzy` would undo what `--xyzzy` would do.  This is mostly useful when the default behavior might be determined by a config option.  So maybe the out-of-the-box default is that the command doesn't order a pizza.  There's an `--order-a-pizza` option.  If the command finds that `$ALWAYS_ORER_A_PIZZA` is set in the environment, then it will order a pizza without the `--order-a-pizza` option; but if, for a particular execution, it shouldn't order a pizza, you can say `--no-order-a-pizza`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax comes from [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form#Table_of_symbols). Square brackets means "an optional part". I.e. the option `--[no-]X` means that both syntax `--X` and `--no-X` are valid. And `--no-X` of course means the reverse of `--X`.

Comment: Good explanation. Now, how can you describe the semantic meaning of "-h,--[no]help" in case of git flow as example? I mean, when you execute a command, there is no help. Why would I have to indicate that I don't want help?

Comment: There are full of these keywords "no" with none sens in my view in this link if it really mean "the inverse of": https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/wiki/Reference:-git-flow-feature

Comment: @Samuel It seems he's implemented `--[no]` for every possible option. :-)

Comment: Hummmm, I'm still concerned about --no-help :)

Comment: @Samuel Yes, it caught my eyes too. :-)))

Answer (score 1):

As it explains on the manual page doing `--assume-unchanged` will set the bit for that option and adding `no-` will unset that option. Having an explicit `no-` option is useful if an option defaults to that being set or your path would normally set that bit and you want to override it with the bit unset.