# git push via proxy

Tags: git

There are a question when i want to use git to push my code to github. when i want to use git to push my code ,it always prompt me this :

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin main
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/smartqy/pythonProject.git/': Unsupported proxy syntax in 'proxyaddress:port'
```

```
$ git config --global --get http.proxy
http[s]://userName:password@proxyaddress:port
```

I do not know how to fix this problem, please help me.

Comment: `[]` means "optional", see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45376096/7976758 That, is, either `https://` or `http://` ; which one works for you we cannot guess, ask your network admins.

Comment: where to find my network admins, i use vpn ,does it have an effect？

Comment: Very much depends on the kind of VPN. For a real VPN you don't need a proxy at all so 1st remove it from config.

Comment: How in the world is your network set up such that you need an HTTP proxy to get to GitHub? O__o

Comment: @amphetamachine Quite an often situation in enterprise: corporate admins are ordered to severely limit outgoing network connections; very often everything must go out via a proxy that intercepts and decrypts all the traffic; official man-in-the-middle, ouch! But I'm not sure about the OP; it seems he just blindly copied text verbatim from some docs without understanding that everything in the string is just a placeholder and must be adapted to his network.

Comment: i am just learning it a few days ,so i don't know these. thanks yours answer